# Django - How can I join a proxy model with another model

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

I explain my scenario:

I have a PurchaseProxy with a calculated field `get_income()` and the model `Purchase` has different fields including one field `date_purchase`. In addition, I have another Model, Outcome with the fields: `date`, `amount` and `description`.

Now, I would an output queryset like this:

```
|| Date || Income || Outcome ||
```

How can I join the Outcome table with the proxy models (which contains `get_income`) without a foreign key?

Comment: Why exactly do you use a proxy model here?

Comment: I use model Purchase for insert data and the proxy shows some statistic (it has two calculated field) for this model.